# merge two splay tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

How to merge two splay tree with amortized cost of log(n)?

Comment: If there are duplicate items in the trees, should the duplicates be merged or not?  For example, if the trees are [1,2,3,4] and [1,2,5] should the result be [1,1,2,2,3,4,5] or [1,2,3,4,5]?

Comment: @niki: it's not that important. assume that duplicate items are not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the splay trees you want to merge hold `n` objects each. (i.e. in total, we have `2n` objects). Then I think it is not possible to merge them with amortized `log(n)` cost, *unless you impose some further assumptions*. If you do not have any information about the objects contained in the trees, you will have to look at least at each element of one of the two trees, thus having cost `O(n)`.

However, if you can make certain assumptions about the objects, you might be able to do it in `O(log(n))`. You might extract certain subtrees so you can insert the whole subtree into the other splay tree. However, I don't know an exact algorithm how to acchieve `O(log(n))`. For example, if we know that the biggest object in `Tree1` is smaller than the smallest object in `Tree2`, then we might just splay the leftmost node of `Tree2` and then we hang the root of `Tree1` under the new root of `Tree2`.

Comment: It helped me a lot. and by the way It's impossible to merge 2 splay tree without any condition in O(Log(n))